# Receiving error after cloning the project : Failed to watch ref error

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a bitbucket project, but I am receiving this error:

```
Failed to watch ref error '/user/.../.git/refs/remotes/origin/master', is most likely packed.
```

What is wrong? How can I fix this?
Is this related to the bitbucket incident?

Comment: Nothing is really wrong, but you're using a Git interface (not the Git command line, some other interface) that's trying to do something Git never supported ("watch" a ref). That's failing, and your non-Git software that you're using with Git may not be able to implement some non-Git feature. If you're depending on that non-Git feature, you might be best off to stop depending on it, since Git doesn't provide it.

Comment: @torek, Thank you, yes, we were just stressed out. it was actually nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was from [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/incidents/r8kyb5w606g5) which was solved latter on